# Is there any way to set Spring error message in Materialize data-error?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, materialize

I would like to validate my form's fields. I am using Materialize Framerwork, Spring Framework and Hibernate Framework. Is there any way to put in data-error label my Spring/Hibernate error message? I did search but did not find anything.

Comment: Different example, but can do what you need after tweaking https://github.com/michaelisvy/ajax-samples

Comment: In addition, post what you have tried with the complete example that includes the form and request to get better help

Comment: What are you using for view engine? e.g. Thymeleaf

Comment: I am using Apache Tiles Framework and JSTL core if it matters

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the view engine you are using.
For e.g i use Thymeleaf and the way i do it is as follows:

Controller Method

```
public String passError(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("labelErrorValue", "This is a generic error message");
   return "test";
}
```

Page

```
<input type="text" id="text_input" name="text_input" class="validate"/>
<label for="text_input" th:attr="data-error=${labelErrorValue}">Input Text</label>
```